# Incompatible static properties in three.d.ts, with latest TypeScript

Tags: static, three.js, typescript

I'm compiling `three.d.ts` (available from [here](https://github.com/kontan/three.d.ts)) with the TypeScript `develop` branch. I get the following error:

```
Types of static property 'Utils' of class 'THREE.Shape' and class 'THREE.Path'
are incompatible
```

The problem is that

- `Shape` defines a static `Utils` class
- `Shape` indirectly inherits from `Curve`
- `Curve` also defines a static `Utils` class with a signature unrelated to `Shape.Utils`

which is ill-formed according to the language spec. Summarised, `three.d.ts` contains something like the following code:

```
declare class A {
   static Utils: {
      f (): any;
   }
}

declare class B extends A {
   static Utils: {
      // incompatible with A.Utils, without f(): any
      g (): any;
   }
}
```

Putting aside the question of why the type of a static member must be compatible with that of an inherited static member of the same name - which isn't the case in several other OO languages, but which does appear to be the case in TypeScript - I would like to know how to fix `three.d.ts` so I can compile it.

My current workaround is simply to copy and paste the signature of `Curve.Utils` into `Shape.Utils`, so that the latter structurally extends the former. But what is the "right" way to capture the signature of the underlying `three.js` file ([here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/f4ce3b666826fb5a140eccbc408baf478708de73/src/Three.js)) in a `.d.ts` file? Is this a case of inheritance being used incorrectly?

Comment: Clarification: this compiles under TypeScript 0.9.1-1, but not under the "develop" branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, per spec, Typescript doesn't allow member hiding through inheritance, like C# does automatically for example.

As defined in the [language specifications](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) section 8.2.3

> A derived class inherits all members from its base class it doesn’t override. Inheritance means that a 
>   derived class implicitly contains all non-overridden members of the base class. Both public and private 
>   members are inherited, but only public members can be overridden. A member in a derived class is said 
>   to override a member in a base class when the derived class member has the same name and kind 
>   (instance or static) as the base class member. **The type of an overriding member must be a subtype 
>   (section 3.8.2) of the type of the overridden member, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs.**

and

> Base class static members can be overridden by derived class static members of any kind as >long as the 
>   types are compatible, as described above.

Maybe they added some type checking into the latest compiler version which was missing before...

Here is a proposed solution, based on inheritance:

```
declare class UtilsA{
    f():any;
}
declare class UtilsB extends UtilsA{
    g():any;
}

declare class A {
   static Utils:UtilsA;
}

declare class B extends A {
   static Utils:UtilsB;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, which is why I specifically said "putting aside the question..." :)

In other words, given that this is the case, how does one correctly encode this aspect of three.js as a three.d.ts file?

Comment: Clarified that the example code I gave is ill-formed according to the spec.

Comment: Great answer. And yes you are correct in that they added further check to enforce the spec

Comment: @Roly I think if you would define a type for Utils in A and B and the type of Utils in B would be a subtype (inherits Utils' type of A) it would work.
If you just define the same property name, Typescript doesn't allow this, you would have to rename at least one of those properties, e.g. B.UtilsB. In this case B would have Utils AND UtilsB

Comment: @Roly added example to my answer

Comment: @MichaC. Thanks for the suggestion. I did wonder about whether to use named types and subtyping. I'm still curious as to whether this it the "correct" way of extracting the interface from three.js. (Maybe the problem is in some of the inheritance relationships instead.)

As an aside, it is possible (in the original JavaScript) to invoke the methods of `Curve.Utils` from the `Shape.Utils` object? If not, then this aspect of the TypeScript language is somewhat inconsistent with JavaScript. (Although I've already said this issue is off-topic, I'm still interested :)

Comment: I mean, in JavaScript you don't have inheritance at all, you would build it somehow manually (as TypeScript does, too). Of cause you could do anything you want in JavaScript, just depends on how the objects are implemented and the inheritance is implemented. Typescript on the other side just puts some restrictions per language definition. This doesn't mean you cannot do it, they just do it to enforce some clean oop style. If you inherit something in TS, the class inherits also the private and static members. In C# you would HIDE the member if your subclass has the same member, TS doesn't ;)

Comment: Static members hide rather than override because it's always known statically which member you're referring to. For instance members that isn't known until runtime when the actual class of the object is known, and therefore overriding semantics (substitutability) is required for soundness. Anyway, I accept the language spec as is. What I would like to know is how to fix `three.d.ts` in a way which is most consistent with the usual way of capturing a JavaScript library in a `.d.ts` file.